# $(window).on('beforeunload', function() not working on sometimes

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

I have use the below code for window close tab. Its working fine. but sometimes not working.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    var i = "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4);?>";
    var j = "<?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];?>";
    var k = "<?php echo base_url();?>";     
    $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/gethost';?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: { id : i , ip: j },
                datatype : "html"
            });
return 'Exit Now!';
});
```

Comment: pls change `var j = "<?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];?>";` to `var j = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>";`

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition.  As your AJAX request is in flight, the browser is tearing down the page and taking your AJAX request with it.  Using synchronous AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    ....
```

will help in some cases (and I've used it myself - empirically, it works) but I don't think anything is *guaranteed* to work here.  Browsers typically put quite severe restrictions on what can be done in `beforeunload`.

Comment: I have used now. But still not working. If I close the tab within few seconds it will work, but after some time the _beforeunload_ event not working.

Comment: Any body give the solution ASAP.